# How to solve an INVALID_RESOURCE_ID problem with PayPal Payouts API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here is my complete error and I am using sandbox credentials to call payout

```
{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","debug_id":"c0b6db41825e9","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors","details":[],"links":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I am using sandbox credentials to call payout" -- where is your call's request body? Difficult for anyone to help when you provide no information.

Try a new, unique `sender_item_id` for each payouts batch request. If it still doesn't work, use a different (new) [sandbox Business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F) and REST app credentials for it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get sender_item_id ? Is there any SDK ?

and I just updated my request body in the questing description .

Comment: Here is my items array 
"items": [
                        {
                          "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                          "receiver": "sb-af8vw6169254@personal.example.com",
                          "note": "POSPYO001",
                          "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                          "amount":
                          {
                            "currency": "INR",
                            "value": "06.00"
                          } 
                        }]

Comment: You don't get one, you provide it. Make it unique for each payouts batch you create.

Comment: And you must use a supported PayPal currency. 'INR' is not supported.

Comment: I changed it to USD also but still getting the same error.
Successfully create a payout but retrieve payout not working
here is my code to retrieve payout
$request = new PayoutsGetRequest($batchId);
 $response = $client->execute($request);
 echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";

Comment: I am able to create a payout but it is in the pending stage.what should I do to complete this ?